# retrieving last two years data from current sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i am stuck on an oracle query wherein i want to retrieve data from previous two years based on the current year like this is 2013 so i want to retrieve all records from year 2011 and 2012 i have done the following query but m getting stuck on date formats  i am pretty new to oracle 
here is the query

```
Select 
to_date(stage_end_date,'yy') Years,SUBPRODUCT Product,sum(OFFER_COUNT) SumCount
    ,sum(offer_amount)SumAmount
from stage_amt  
and 
Offer_amount !=0 
and 
to_date(stage_end_date,'yy')
between to_char( sysdate, -2 ) and to_char( sysdate)
group by to_date(stage_end_date,'yy'),SUBPRODUCT
order by Years asc;
```

m getting this error
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
can any one help me what to do

regards

Comment: what data type is `stage_end_date`

Comment: Then why do you use `to_date()` on it? `to_date()` converts a character value to a date value. It's useless to use when you already *have* a date.

Comment: yaa sorry for that in the original query i had to_char i guess i might have put the query on which i was doing r&d but its helping me to learn new things such errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
where stage_end_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') - interval '2' year
  and stage_end_date <  trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy');
```

Answer (score 1):

with sysdate you are appling to_char function but giving incorrect date formate  -

I believe that stage_end_date is a date column, if so, I think you need to use to_char function in place of to_date in select query ... try below query -

```
Select To_Char(stage_end_date,'yy') Years,
       SUBPRODUCT Product,
       sum(OFFER_COUNT) SumCount,
       sum(offer_amount)SumAmount
from stage_amt  
where Offer_amount !=0 
  and to_number(To_char(stage_end_date,'YYYY')) between 
      to_number(to_char( sysdate,'YYYY'))-2 and to_number(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY'))
group by to_char(stage_end_date,'yy'),
         SUBPRODUCT
order by Years asc;
```

Although Oracle will take care or data conversion from string to number while comparing but for safer side I have wrote `TO_NUMBER` function also while comparing dates.

Comment: hi pratik thx for the reply i had one more doubt how will i retrieve data say of 2011 from the current sysdate without hardcoding by keeping the above query in mind its returning 2011 and 2012 data right now if i only want 2011 data or 2010 data what will be the query

Comment: @Oraclerookie this is depending on your sysdate, suppose your sysdate is the same as today April 8, 2013 then you need to change the second condition in where clause as 
'and to_number(To_char(stage_end_date,'YYYY')) = to_number(to_char( sysdate,'YYYY'))-2' (for 2011 records) and so on for other result. basically this condition you need to think and write as per your requirement.